# Audio tag in Facebook iOS in-app browser

Tags: iphone, facebook, html5-audio, facebook-ios-sdk

I have a webpage with an audio tag in it. It works fine in Mobile Safari.

However, when I open the link from the Facebook app on iOS, it opens in the in-app browser. Here, the audio refuses to play. It will show that it's playing if the controls are showing but there's no audio. Video seems to work fine but the audio tag does not work.

Is there a way to make this work or even to force the link to open in Mobile Safari instead?

To try it out, share http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_soundmidiembed on your facebook wall and try opening it through the iOS app.