# JPlayer not playing audio via mobile Facebook app browser

Tags: facebook, browser, instagram, jplayer

Our situation is this: we have a website which utilizes JPlayer to produce an audio track (mp3, m4a, ogg) that works fine in all browsers besides Facebook's built-in browser for its mobile app (which is also used by Instagram).

Now, via the Instagram app from your phone, we have a link in our "Bio" redirecting followers to the actual website, which plays the track. The problem is that when a user links from our Instagram page, they will be redirected to that page via Instagram's built-in Facebook browser, as opposed to Safari (in which it works perfectly fine). Once this happens, the user cannot listen to the audio track at all. We figure this will affect our traffic negatively, because the user will not be able to play the track from their mobile devices, and thus give up instead of relaunching Safari and playing it from there, or even visiting the website from their desktop or laptop PCs.

Is there any way to get around this? Does JPlayer work at all through Facebook's built-in web browser (the same which Instagram utilizes by default when the mobile Facebook app is installed)?

Comment: A similar question was posed here but there was no answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912511/audio-tag-in-facebook-ios-in-app-browser?rq=1

Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to force the Facebook/Instagram app to launch Safari by default?